# How can I change text on the button Imagerow OpenCms 9

Tags: button, opencms

How can I change text on the button "read more" Image row elements in OpenCms 9?
http://hydra.rs.net.ua:8180/opencms/opencms/RS/licenses.html

I need change language from English to Ukraine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the module of com.alkacon.bootstrap.schema (i suppose you have not clone it or changed the name) in the folder of "i18n", edit xmlvfsbundle file type, with name "com.alkacon.bootstrap.schema.imagerow". 
In the edit mode in the top you can select other language and chage the text for that language.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't find this one. But in my OpenCms I see only English and German, is there any opportunity to add other languages (Russian/Ukranian)?

Comment: Yes, you can. But you will have to copy your text to the new locale (language). In the folder "Config" under /WEB-INF/ you will find the file "opencms-system". Open it and add more locale. 
example:
<localesconfigured>
.
.
<locale>ru</locale>
<locale>uk</locale>
</localesconfigured>
and in
<localesdefault><locale>ru</locale><locale>uk</locale></localesdefault>
i not sure about the locale, i get it from here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes